# Ticker won't cycle round and stops before reaches bottom

Tags: jquery, ticker

I have tried to make a ticker on the right hand column of the majority of pages on this website: http://www.black-kite.co.uk/services [for example].

It works partially. For some reason the ticker doesn't reach the bottom of the last item, and stops rotating. I want it to rotate in an endless loop.

The jquery used is here:

```
$(function() {  

  //cache the ticker  
  var ticker = $("#ticker");  

  //wrap dt:dd pairs in divs  
  ticker.children().filter("dt").each(function() {  

    var dt = $(this),  
      container = $("<div>");  

    dt.next().appendTo(container);  
    dt.prependTo(container);            
    container.appendTo(ticker);  
  });  

  //hide the scrollbar  
  ticker.css("overflow", "hidden");  

  //animator function  
  function animator(currentItem) {  

    //work out new anim duration  
    var distance = currentItem.height(),  
    duration = (distance - Math.abs(parseInt(currentItem.css("marginTop")))) / 0.025;  

    //animate the first child of the ticker  
    currentItem.animate({ marginTop: -distance }, duration, "linear", function() {  

      //move current item to the bottom     
      currentItem.appendTo(currentItem.parent()).css("marginTop", 0);  

    //recurse  
    animator(currentItem.parent().children(":first"));  
    });   
  };  

  //start the ticker  
  animator(ticker.children(":first"));  

  //set mouseenter  
ticker.mouseenter(function() {  

  //stop current animation  
  ticker.children().stop();  

});  

//set mouseleave  
ticker.mouseleave(function() {  

  //resume animation  
  animator(ticker.children(":first"));  
});  

});
```

I have also made a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BsjpV/

I would appreciate any help or pointers, I am only just learning jquery/javascript type stuff! Thank you!

Comment: I don't see those two problems http://jsfiddle.net/mattydsw/BsjpV/1/ Which browser do you use?

Comment: i have tried Chrome, Safari and Firefox. I don't see them rotate round at all... but looking at the jquery where you have put pics in [sorry i forgot to put actual pics in!] i see that you have changed nothing but it works...
I am very confused now!

Comment: when you look at it on black-kite.co.uk/about.php for example [rhs bar, in the clients/partners box] does it work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your help - it was a line of code commented out inadvertently that was doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Line of code commented out inadvertently was the thing causing the problem...